# Identify Book with Intelligent Aquatic Creature over Yellow Hypnotic Swirl on Cover

Tags: story-identification

This was a teen-oriented sci fi novel published in the late 70s or early 80s. It involved kids (possibly related) who journeyed to a land described as having diamonds strewn about like common rocks.

My most vivid memory is the book cover, with an Intelligent Aquatic Creature against Yellow/Green Hypnotic Swirl background.

Thank you

Comment: Realize: LOTS of cover art got reused. And many times, a new printing got new cover art.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the sci-fi part? What were the sci-fi aspects of the book?

Comment: The 'diamonds strewn like common rocks' made me think of Alan Dean Foster's "Carnivores of Light and Darkness" (well, the third book).  There's definately some scenes with the diamond-pebble beach.  As for the rest, there is an aquatic seaweed-man (with king-crab) though I don't recall it on the cover I saw.  The journey-ers were often childish, but not actually kids, and the novel is somewhat newer.  So, probably *not* it, but there seem to be some similarities.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/209212/teenagers-find-an-ancient-lizard-creature-in-stasis-and-accompany-him-on-adventu (which is newer but has an answer confirmed by OP comment)

Answer (score 5):

I think it is the following, which I read and loved when I was a teen.

[*Stranger from the Depths* by Gerry Turner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BTO0NI).

[image: Book cover]

Found the answer on [What's That Book](http://www.whatsthatbook.com/?xq=12).

Descriptions of the book:

> "After sleeping for thousands of years the last survivor of a lost civilization returns to life to reveal secrets of the earth's core never imagined."
>
> "a fantastic tale of two brothers who encounter strange beings who live below the ocean floor."
>
> "It came out in the early 70's and was about the discovery of a coffin shaped stasis box buried under the ocean containing the last surviving member of an intelligent amphibious race..." "...a green man with webbed hands and feet"
>
> "...underwater cities of Haad and Gaan"
>
> "...A statue of one of the reptillian people. One of the reptillians separated from his people (maybe because of suspended animation?), ... The book started off with the protagonists setting up to photograph a tidal wave, with the wave washing away the rock exposing the diamond statue. The lizard's name was 'Saa', he liked peanut butter and jelly sandwiches..."
>
> "... first Gary and his older brother filmed a tsunami, after which they came across a small statue of a mysterious ... Then Gary and his ... girlfriend Lori 'fess up about the underwater cave they've been sneaking away to, leading adults to organize a diving expedition to see what's down there. They find a large cavern containing a suspended animation capsule that contains a dead ringer for their statue. After they manage to revive him, their new friend Saa leads them down to his abandoned city underwater."